# Is Xanthomonas a host-specific disease?

Tags: diseases, peppers, bell-peppers, cucurbits

I grew some volunteer cantaloupes in pots this summer, but they got hit hard by what I believe is [Xanthomonas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthomonas), a bacteria which causes angular leaf spot.

I tossed the diseased plants, but I'd like to use the old soil to pot up some pepper plants so I can bring them inside for the winter.  Is this a risky move?  Can whichever species of Xanthomonas that hits cantaloupes (a curcubit) infest my peppers (a nightshade)?  Or, is this disease specific enough to its host that it won't harm plants in other genuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call it a very risky move - if you know the previous occupants of soil within a pot suffered a fungal or bacterial infection, it's not a sensible move to re use the same soil for other plants. If you have a garden, spread the soil from the pots over the ground, unless you live somewhere that doesn't get chilly or cold winters - areas that remain fairly warm even during winter may mean whatever the organism is that caused the problem might survive in open ground. Wash and sterilize the pots before refilling with fresh planting medium.

Xanthomonas comes in many varieties, and most are host specific - even so, I wouldn't risk re-using that soil, for you cannot be 100% certain the infective organism was actually X. curcurbitae, or Xanthomonas at all, without laboratory tests. The infective agent might actually have been downy mildew caused by Pseudoperonospora anyway, which also causes angular leaf spot initially. Added to that, there may be other nasties in the soil which, once brought into the heat indoors for winter, will thrive. But, ultimately, it's up to you whether you risk it or not.